# Produce a list of Lucas/fibonacci sequence with Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, append, arity

I am just fiddling with prolog a little an I've come across a problem I don't know how to solve. I want to create a procedure that returns the [Lucas sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number) of a given number In. I have got the code to return the actual number down, but it does just that, return the Lucas value of the number In. What I want is to return a list with all the Lucas sequence numbers up to that one. I've bee trying to do it and I've just got no idea how to implement this. Below is my attempt. Any help would be appreciated!!!

```
lucas(0,[2]).
lucas(1,[2,1]).
lucas(In,Exit):- 
    In>1,
    First is In-1, Second is In-2, 
    lucas(First, First1),lucas(Second,Second1), 
    [Out] is First1+Second1, 
    Lucas(1,L),
    app([L],Out,Exit).
```

Comment: So you want to `accumulate` the answers. Prolog has a concept called accumulator for just that. See: [Accumulators](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/courses/esslli04prolog/practical.day3.php?s=practical.day3.node10)

Comment: Your code does not run on my machine. You might want to investigate the goal `Lucas(1,L)` as first step. Also the line above does not have any solutions. A good start would be to find out why `[Out] is 1` does not have any solutions but `Out is 1` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution is to define the Lucas numbers and afterwards producing a list of Lucas numbers:

```
% Definition of Lucas numbers according to Wikipedia
lucas(0, 2) :- !.
lucas(1, 1) :- !.
lucas(N, R) :-
    N > 1,
    N_Pre is N - 1,
    N_PrePre is N - 2,
    lucas(N_Pre, LHS),
    lucas(N_PrePre, RHS),
    R is LHS + RHS.

% Memoization of Lucas numbers
:- table lucas/2.

% Generate List
seq(M, Result) :-
    numlist(0, M, List),
    maplist(lucas, List, Result).
```

If I then call, seq, it produces a sequence of Lucas numbers:

```
?- seq(5, R).
R = [2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11].
```